# The order of duplicate values in the pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas

How can I add a new column in pandas DataFrame which enumerates all repeated values. In the example below, I have 3 repeated `865432` values in column B. I want to add a column which will have values 0, 1 and 2 associated with different `865432` values.

Input table

```
A       B
0  865432
1  865432
2  134567
3  865432
4  134567
5  222222
```

Output table

```
A       B  C
0  865432  0
1  865432  1
3  865432  2
2  134567  0
4  134567  1
5  222222  0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html#pandas.Series.groupby) on 'B' column and then call [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount):

```
In [345]:

df['C'] = df.groupby('B', as_index=False)['B'].cumcount()
df
Out[345]:
   A       B  C
0  0  865432  0
1  1  865432  1
2  2  134567  0
3  3  865432  2
4  4  134567  1
5  5  222222  0
```